# SQL Server - Shuffling rows

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, random

I am currently building a matching type of test in vb.net and I want to know how to shuffle rows.

I have a table named 'Exercise' and it has column 'Question' and 'Answer' in it.

I want to retrieve the questions (10 items) in-order (and then store it in one textbox each item) but retrieve the answers shuffled (one textbox each item as well) to avoid adjacent question and its correct answer.

I've tried this:
Select * from exercise where lessonno = ’1’ order by newid()

It returns randomly but with duplicates. I need it without repetition.

I think i should use distinct but i dont know how.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please ***show your code***, we would be glad to help but you need to show an attempt.

Comment: Have you tried using  `select top 10 ... order by newid()`?

Comment: @JamesZ but he wants to get 10 records, and then randomize just answers such that each question does not be beside its actual answer... Is this true?

Comment: Yes @S.Serp that is exactly what i need.

Comment: why your query return duplicates? what are those repeated rows? do you have same questions or answers in your db? please give an example data and duplicate results

Comment: Maybe because order by newid() just selects random row, not shuffling. I have no same questions nor answers.

Comment: `order by newid()` selects random rows, but it does not cause any duplicate. recheck your data.

Comment: Also, for randomize the answers, you have to shuffle those valuesafter you get data from database (in your vb code, not sql)

Answer (score 0):

If we are at the same page I understood this,
There is an approach for this, lets assume that you have 4 answers and 1 question in your table. 
Question 1: What is the color of the sky? A: Blue B: Yellow C: Green D: Pink

This question and answers are stored in your table. I your app, in order to get your the same question as like this,
Question 1: What is the color of the sky? A: Yellow B: Blue C: Pink D: Green
You shoul define an array and insert randomly values in it.

[image]

this algorithm will generate random options everytime, like
(1,2,4,3),(2,1,3,4),(4,3,1,2)

match your options with those numbers. For example, A=1 B=2 C=3 D=4 and if you list your question choices considering thisrandom numbered array you will get the same question with different answer order.

Comment: my algorithm may not be working proparly I have not tested it. But the main Idea is to create 4 number randomly in an aray and list the choices  with respect to arrays values